# Laravel соединение моделей через массив ключей

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Имеется таблицы users и city.
В таблице users есть поле cities, которое представляет собой строку вида [1,2,3,4...], где каждое число - id города из таблицы city.
Каким образом можно реализовать соединение таблицы users с city, через идентификаторы в таком виде?
Что-то типа

```
User::leftJoin('cities', 'users.cities', 'cities.id')->get();
```

Даже в виде чистого sql не очень представляю какой должен быть запрос, что бы перевести его в laravel.

Comment: Надо просто изменить структуру хранения и нормализовать данные. А заодно надавать по рогам тому гению, который придумал свалить данные в CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет возможности переделать базу можно поступить следующим образом:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public functions cities()
    {
         return City::whereIn('id', explode(',', $this->cities);
    }

    public function getCitiesAttribute()
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('cities', $this->relations)) {
             $this->load('cities');
        }
        return $this->getRelation('cities');
    }
}

...

foreach($user->cities as $city) {
    echo($city->name);
}
```